# Neo4j 3.0 and spring data

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I would like to use the new bolt protocol to connect my spring application to neo4j 3.0 database.

Is bolt protocol already implemented in spring data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these versions support Bolt:

Neo4j OGM 2.0.2, which can be used with SDN 4.1.1.RELEASE (you will need to explicitly include this Neo4j OGM version).

Or the current SDN snapshot 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT which depends on the latest Neo4j OGM snapshot.

The Bolt Driver dependency is also required:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Configuration for the Bolt driver is documented at http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/#_configuring_the_bolt_driver

Comment: After I included the right version can I use as before  
       public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
  return new RemoteServer(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
 }

Comment: Afraid not, with the introduction of drivers in SDN 4.1, RemoteServer does not exist any more. It's quite simple though- http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_spring_configuration

Comment: When is it planned the release 4.2.0 of SDN?